# How to get the cwd (current working directory) from a nodejs child process (in both windows and linuxish)

Tags: node.js, process

I'm trying to run a script via nodejs that does:

```
cd ..
doSomethingThere[]
```

However, to do this, I need to executed multiple child processes and carry over the environment state between those processes. What i'd like to do is:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child1 = exec('cd ..', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  var child2 = exec('cd ..', child1.environment, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  });
});
```

or at very least:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child1 = exec('cd ..', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  var child2 = exec('cd ..', {cwd: child1.process.cwd()}, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  });
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Look into fibers or one of the many worker thread libs for node; save yourself a ton of energy and take advantage of libs that have already solved the hundreds of issues you'll face like this one.

Comment: @Kato I use fibers. It has literally nothing to do with what I'm asking about. If the worker thread libs you're talking about are at all similar, they're not helpful in this case.

Answer (score 46):

to start child with parent dir as cwd:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var path = require('path')

var parentDir = path.resolve(process.cwd(), '..');
exec('doSomethingThere', {cwd: parentDir}, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  // if you also want to change current process working directory:
  process.chdir(parentDir);
});
```

**Update**: if you want to retrieve child's cwd:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var os = require('os');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function getCWD(pid, callback) {
  switch (os.type()) {
  case 'Linux':
    fs.readlink('/proc/' + pid + '/cwd', callback); break;
  case 'Darwin':
    exec('lsof -a -d cwd -p ' + pid + ' | tail -1 | awk \'{print $9}\'', callback);
    break;
  default:
    callback('unsupported OS');
  }
}

// start your child process
//    note that you can't do like this, as you launch shell process 
//    and shell's child don't change it's cwd:
// var child1 = exec('cd .. & sleep 1 && cd .. sleep 1');
var child1 = exec('some process that changes cwd using chdir syscall');

// watch it changing cwd:
var i = setInterval(getCWD.bind(null, child1.pid, console.log), 100);
child1.on('exit', clearInterval.bind(null, i));
```

Comment: Hey Andrey, this solves the contrived example problem I came up with, but it still doesn't answer the main question of how to get the working directory from a child process.

Comment: you need your child process to report its working directory? It is set initially by `cwd` option. If you need to know what it was before child exit, send it from child via some RPC call (simplest is just to print to stdout)

Comment: I'm actually trying to run arbitrary shell commands that could include commands that change the cwd (like "cd").

Comment: You can't change parent process cwd from child process (Unless parent process does it itself based on some notification from child)

Comment: This is the answer. The above comment is one of the biggest misconceptions about a program's CWD.

Comment: @Qix, please note that how to change a parent's CWD was *not* the question. The question was how to get the cwd of a child process which has been running and may have changed its own cwd since launching. Hence the answer I gave. I'm not sure why you just downvoted it.

Comment: Heh, I run windows, so I'll have to get back to this once I've set up dual booting (which I plan to do soon).

Answer (score 25):

If you want to get the current working directory without resorting to OS specific command line utilities, you can use the "battled-tested" shelljs library that abstract these things for you, while underneath using child processes.

```
var sh = require("shelljs");
var cwd = sh.pwd();
```

There you have it, the variable cwd holds your current working directory whether you're on Linux, Windows, or freebsd.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought, if you know the child process's PID, and have [pwdx](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwdx) installed (likely on linux), you could execute that command from node to get the child's cwd.

Comment: +1 Definitely sounds like a working answer. Would be great if there was a way to do it without messing with command line utilities tho

Comment: OSX solution: `OSX: `lsof -a -d cwd -p [pid]`. On linux, instead of pwdx one can just do `ls -l /proc/[pid]/cwd` (or, from node: `require('fs').readlinkSync('/proc/123456/cwd')` )

Comment: anything for windows?

Comment: @BT I don't know off the top of my head how to do such a thing on Windows. You should consider asking that as a new question if you're looking for an answer.

Comment: Why would I ask it as a different question - its the same question, just on multiple platforms

Comment: @BT Because different platform = different experts. This question is several months old, and is unlikely to attract the attention of anyone new.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best bet is manipulating the `options.cwd` between calls to `exec`. in `exec` callback `this.pwd` and `this.cwd` might give you leverage for your implementations.