# How to follow the cwd path of a exec child process [Mac / Windows]

Tags: node.js, shell

I am making a very simple nodeJs based terminal.
There is an edit text box for the user to enter the commands. An the nodeJs script will exec the command and show the result.

The basis of this is

```
result = exec(evalLines, evalCallBack);
```

If the user types `ls` in in the edit box then it will show the __dirname directory contents. If he changes the directory `cd ..` then the directory will change to the parent directory. So far all said is very obvious.

How can I follow where the cwd is changed to?

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Terminal</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Enter the Shell commands in the top box and press Shift + Enter to execute it</h3>
    <form>
    <textarea type="text" id="execCode" style="width: 100%; height: 100px">cd ./Users 
ls
    </textarea>
    </form>
    <textarea type="text" id="execResult" style="width: 100%; height: 100px"></textarea>
    <span id="restartExt1">Restart Extension</span>
    <script src="../js/libs/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/buttons2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Teminal.js**

```
(function() {
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    var evalCallBack = function(error, result) {
        // looking to change the '@' to the NEW current working domain
        $("#execResult").val((error || result) + '@$ \n');
    };

    $('#execCode').keypress(function(key) {
        if (key.keyCode == 13 && key.shiftKey) {
            exec($('#execCode').val(), evalCallBack);
        }
    });  
})();
```

What I am looking to do is replace the '@$' with the new directory.

[image]

Note I saw [How to get the cwd (current working directory) from a nodejs child process (in both windows and linuxish)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939380/how-to-get-the-cwd-current-working-directory-from-a-nodejs-child-process-in-b) but the answers didn't help me.

Comment: By the looks of it, you need to parse `$('#execCode').val()` manually to see if it contains a `cd` command, and store its value in between `exec()` calls.

Comment: That would be a real pain in the neck

Comment: One problem is that you're starting a new child process for each command, which means that those commands run completely independent of each other. A directory change in one does not propagate to the next.

Comment: @robertklep do you have a suggestion of how one can do this without starting a new child process for each command? That would be very good.

Comment: I don't think it's trivial to implement. You'd have to start a long-running shell process and somehow communicate with that. Alternatively, you implement your own shell, but like I said, that will mean having to implement built-in commands, like a regular shell does (`cd` is such a built-in, it's not an external program that the shell executes).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it sounds like I can forget about it unless somebody here comes up with some voodoo.