# child-process exec cwd, is not setting current working directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am building a node.js application.
For executing a command, I am using child-process.
I have to need to change CWD(current working directory) before executing the command. so I have code like below.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

  let opts = {
    "maxBuffer": 1024 * 5000,
    "timeout": toolTimeout,
    "cwd": /opt/somepath,
    "env": {
      "PATH": process.env.PATH + ':' + /opt/somepath,
      "LANG": "en_US.UTF-8"
    }
  };
  exec(command, opts, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
}
```

but above setup is not working as its still not changing CWD before executing command and command is executing from current directory where node file resides.
Please help, if someone has any idea.

Comment: I think you pass an absolute path to the cwd option. Use `path.resolve()` to generate an absolute path and pass it.

Comment: yes, i am passing absolute path,so you are suggesting to pas abs_path = path.resolve(some_path) ?

Comment: yes, generate an absolute path of cwd and pass it to `exec`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the code snippet you pasted should work and CWD should change current directory as per your value.

though i am suspecting as you are explicitly setting env.

```
"env": {
      "PATH": process.env.PATH + ':' + /opt/somepath,
      "LANG": "en_US.UTF-8"
    }
```

you may override all other value of env but you are just setting PATH and LANG in env. Overriding env maybe harmful as it may contain several other variables and values, which may finally cause to failure of any dependent command.

try to do it like below.

```
let opts = {
    "maxBuffer": 1024 * 5000,
    "timeout": toolTimeout,
    "cwd": /opt/somepath,
     "env": process.env
  };
  opts.env.PATH = opts.env.PATH + ':' + nlu_plmtool_dir;
  exec(command, opts, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
}
```

by doing this you will set PATH in env and preserve already set value in env too.

Comment: thanks, that was my mistake.Its working after doing alteration as you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue. This is how I sorted it out

```
exec('cd newDirectoryName && someOtherCommandForThatDirectoru' , (error, stdout, stderr)=>{...}
```

This way you can do all that in just on command.

May be helpful. Thanks

Comment: as i am setting CWD, i am especting that CWD will dictate command execution directory, is it neccesary to explicitly put directory information in command itself?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer to a similar use-case of yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939380/how-to-get-the-cwd-current-working-directory-from-a-nodejs-child-process-in-b/23590860).  You could also go ahead and use [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) for capturing the path.